# Pulling 2 independent queries and then combined into one subquery in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, correlated-subquery

[enter image description here] sample data set
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyNig.jpg)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqpqP.jpg)My question involves putting up 2 independent queries. First, I need to pull the products that are contained in all the stores. The second query is to gather all the products and list the sizes available. Once I made the 2 queries, I can combine them into one subquery. I'm running SQL Server.

So far I got the first part, where I was able to obtain the product ID of those available in all stores. This only outputs the product ID, my strategy was to then have an outer query to evaluate those and join it with the sizes table.

```
SELECT product_id
FROM Sells
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(store_location_id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM store_location);
```

I'm now trying to get the 2nd query going for the sizes. Can anyone point at what am I missing? I'm getting an error showing available_in. product ID could not be bound.

[image]

I added the ERD to clarify the tables. I'm assuming I have to join the tables between Product to Available_in and join available_in to Sizes. I'm trying to output the name, size option, product_id

[image]

Comment: Share sample data and expected output

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.  Please show sample input and output.

Comment: so the first independent query would pull in an output showing the product_id that is available in every store, which I did. It will pull up product_id of 101 and 103.  The second query should pull up size_option column and the product_id column.    Once both queries are combined via subquery, the outer query should be the size options. The subquery would be the one I created to pull the product_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the Question you only want to know how to **join two queries**?

I've made a couple of changes to your second query the list of tables (Sizes, Available_in, Sells), I've removed the "Available_in, Sells" because they represent a cross join when placed there.

I've also stayed away from interpreting the queries provided not knowing the actual context of the tables.  However for clarity the query asks for:

> A list of unique product ids where the number of store locations that product is sold in matches the number of stores in the store location table, that is where the product is being sold in all the stores.

```
SELECT size_option, available_in.product_id, product.product_name
FROM Sizes
JOIN available_in ON Available_in.sizes_id = Sizes.sizes_id
JOIN Product ON Product.product_id = Available_in.product_id
```

There are several ways to do that depending on the version of SQL Server you're using Common Table Expressions (CTE) were introduced in SQL Server 2005.  Two examples are outlined below.

***SQL Server before 2005***

```
SELECT size_option, available_in.product_id, product.product_name
FROM Sizes
JOIN available_in ON Available_in.sizes_id = Sizes.sizes_id
JOIN Product ON Product.product_id = Available_in.product_id

WHERE product.product_id in (
   SELECT product_id
   FROM Sells
   GROUP BY product_id
   HAVING COUNT(store_location_id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM store_location)

)
```

***SQL Server 2005 and above***

```
WITH ProductIDList as (
   SELECT product_id
   FROM Sells
   GROUP BY product_id
   HAVING COUNT(store_location_id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM store_location)

)
, ProductInfo as (
   SELECT size_option, available_in.product_id, product.product_name
   FROM Sizes
   JOIN available_in ON Available_in.sizes_id = Sizes.sizes_id
   JOIN Product ON Product.product_id = Available_in.product_id

)
SELECT *
FROM ProductInfo 
JOIN ProductIDList ON ProductInfo.product_id = ProductIDList.product_id
```

Comment: How would I format it if i want to use the subquery in the FROM clause, skipping the WHERE CLAUSE.

Comment: SELECT size_option, available_in.product_id, product.product_name
    FROM Sizes
    JOIN available_in ON Available_in.sizes_id = Sizes.sizes_id
    JOIN Product ON Product.product_id = Available_in.product_id
    JOIN (
       SELECT product_id
       FROM Sells
       GROUP BY product_id
       HAVING COUNT(store_location_id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM store_location)
   
    ) AS ProdIDs ON ProdIDs.product_id = Product.product_id

Answer (score 0):

I would simply `JOIN` them together.  Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**  `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

```
select s.size_option, ai.product_id, p.product_name
from Sizes s join
     available_in ai
     on ai.sizes_id = s.sizes_id join
     Product p
     on p.product_id = ai.product_id join
     (select se.product_id
      from sells se
      group by se.product_id
      having count(se.store_location_id) = (select count(*) from store_location
     ) se
     on se.product_id = p.product_id;
```

You'll note that this also includes table aliases, which make the query easier to write and to read.